# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I wanna to do a chat application when the user typing a URL or mail text will become hyperlink `google.com` / `abc123@gmail.com` similar like Whatsapp and Facebook Messenger. But now my code can't type anything will get the error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

I have no idea how to fix this problem.
I research Google doesn't get any help for me.

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    import re
    class Ui_Form(object):
        def setupUi(self, Form):
            Form.setObjectName("Form")
            Form.resize(400, 300)
            self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Form)
            self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 361, 192))
            self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
            self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
            self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 220, 93, 28))
            self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
            self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
            self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 210, 271, 41))
            self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")

            self.retranslateUi(Form)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getvalue)


        def retranslateUi(self, Form):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
            self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))

        def getvalue(self,email):
             s = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
             p = re.match("^.+@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$",str (email))
             q = re.compile("^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$",re.IGNORECASE)
             if (p != None and self.getvalue(s) == True):
                 links ='{1}'.format(('mailto:'+s), s)
                 self.textBrowser.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
                 self.textBrowser.setText(links)
                 print("s")
             elif (q != None and self.getvalue(s) == True):
                 link ='{1}'.format(('http://'+s), s)
                 self.textBrowser.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
                 self.textBrowser.setText(link)
                 print("t")
             else:
                 self.textBrowser.append(s)
                 print("u")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_Form()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> Blockquote

The result :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_trace_dispatch_regular.py",
>   line 373, in **call**
>       if not is_stepping and frame_cache_key in cache_skips: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison Fatal
>   Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
>
> Thread 0x00003700 (most recent call first):   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py",
>   line 176 in _on_run   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py",
>   line 203 in run   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 885
>   in _bootstrap   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py",
>   line 626 in **call**
>
> Thread 0x000029a4 (most recent call first):   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 300 in wait   File
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 552 in
>   wait   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py",
>   line 154 in _on_run   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py",
>   line 203 in run   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 885
>   in _bootstrap   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py",
>   line 626 in **call**
>
> Thread 0x00003c94 (most recent call first):   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\wrapper.py",
>   line 383 in recv   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py",
>   line 273 in _on_run   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py",
>   line 203 in run   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 885
>   in _bootstrap
>
> Thread 0x00001318 (most recent call first):   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\ipcjson.py",
>   line 112 in _send   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\ipcjson.py",
>   line 279 in send_event   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\wrapper.py",
>   line 2558 in on_pydevd_cmd_write_to_console2   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\wrapper.py",
>   line 1386 in on_pydevd_event   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\session.py",
>   line 181 in handle_pydevd_message   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\daemon.py",
>   line 531 in _handle_pydevd_message   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\wrapper.py",
>   line 423 in send   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py",
>   line 522 in send   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py",
>   line 365 in _on_run   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py",
>   line 203 in run   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 885
>   in _bootstrap
>
> Thread 0x00002658 (most recent call first):   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\ipcjson.py",
>   line 131 in _buffered_read_line_as_ascii   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\ipcjson.py",
>   line 172 in _wait_for_message   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\ipcjson.py",
>   line 318 in process_one_message   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\ipcjson.py",
>   line 305 in process_messages   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\wrapper.py",
>   line 906 in process_messages   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865 in run   File
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917 in
>   _bootstrap_inner   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap
>
> Thread 0x00000df0 (most recent call first):   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 300 in wait   File
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 552 in
>   wait   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\futures.py",
>   line 106 in run_forever   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865 in run   File
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917 in
>   _bootstrap_inner   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap
>
> Current thread 0x00001154 (most recent call first):   File
>   "c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_trace_dispatch_regular.py",
>   line 373 in **call**   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\enum.py", line 607 in value   File "C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\types.py", line 171 in **get**   File
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 274 in _compile
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 234 in
>   compile   File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\python\test.py", line 42 in
>   getvalue   File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\python\test.py", line 48 in
>   getvalue   File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\python\test.py", line 48 in
>   getvalue   ...

Comment: Unsurprisingly, you call `self.getvalue(s) == True` from within `self.getvalue()` . You have no stop condition so you will always recurse deeper. You have to revisit your program logic to fix this.

Comment: Sorry, do you have any example? I need to reference.

Comment: Look in your subroutine `.getvalue`. There you call `.getvalue` again. And call `.getvalue` again, and again.

Comment: tq!!! I solve the problem